# Oracle: Over Partition By not working when specifying the column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data

```
VEHICLE        DATE      INCIDENTS       SERVICE       AVG_NO
 x50        01/01/2020        2             1             20
 X50        09/01/2020        1             0             20
```

I am planning to create a column for incidents and services where it takes sum of all the incidents and services for the last (AVG_NO) days

```
SELECT VEHICLE, DATE, 
SUM(INCIDENTS) over (partition by VEHICLE order by DATE rows between AVG_NO preceding and current row) as SUM_INCIDENTS,
SUM(SERVICE) over (partition by VEHICLE order by DATE rows between AVG_NO preceding and current row) as SUM_SERVICE
from TBL
```

But the problem with the above script is that, the over and partition by is not working.
In place of the AVG_NO, if I specify a number it works.

```
SELECT VEHICLE, DATE, 
SUM(INCIDENTS) over (partition by VEHICLE order by DATE rows between 20 preceding and current row) as SUM_INCIDENTS,
SUM(SERVICE) over (partition by VEHICLE order by DATE rows between 20 preceding and current row) as SUM_SERVICE
from TBL
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to debug "it is not working" if you don't explain *what* is not working.

Looking at what you posted, and if you use Oracle (as you tagged it), then `DATE` is an invalid column name as it is reserved for datatype. If that's fixed (I used `datum` column name instead), query returns *something*:

```
SQL> with test (vehicle, datum, incidents, service, avg_no) as
  2    (select 'x50', date '2020-01-01', 2, 1, 20 from dual union all
  3     select 'x50', date '2020-01-09', 1, 0, 20 from dual
  4    )
  5  select vehicle, datum,
  6    sum(incidents) over (partition by vehicle order by datum
  7                         rows between avg_no preceding and current row
  8                        ) as sum_incidents,
  9    sum(service)   over (partition by vehicle order by datum
 10                         rows between avg_no preceding and current row
 11                        ) as sum_service
 12  from test;

VEH DATUM      SUM_INCIDENTS SUM_SERVICE
--- ---------- ------------- -----------
x50 01.01.2020             2           1
x50 09.01.2020             3           1

SQL>
```

I don't know if that's what you wanted, but it didn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the `AVG_NO > 0`  or you can make it 1 if it is 0.

```
SELECT VEHICLE, DATE, 
SUM(INCIDENTS) over (partition by VEHICLE order by DATE rows between decode(AVG_NO,0,1,AVG_NO) preceding 
and current row) as SUM_INCIDENTS,
SUM(SERVICE) over (partition by VEHICLE order by DATE rows between decode(AVG_NO,0,1,AVG_NO) preceding 
and 
current row) as SUM_SERVICE
from TBL;
```